# Delete a UserForm and add a New UserForm in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, userform

What I would like to do is Delete a Userform and replace it with an updated Userform using VBA for Excel.

I exported the original Userform, made my changes, and now would like to replace the original with the new Userform. Both Userforms have the same names. I'm hoping, by keeping the UserForm names the same the button that activates the Userform won't be damaged.

I have am going to have the VBA loop through all the workbooks and do this ~3200 times.

```
Sub Macro2() 
'''delete and replace a UserForm

'Dim some stuff
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim SourceRow As Long
    Dim EditRow As Long
    Dim sFile As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim FileName1 As String
    Dim FileName2 As String
    Dim wksSource As Worksheet
    Const scWkbSourceName As String = "theFILE.xlsm"

    Set wkbSource = Workbooks(scWkbSourceName)
    Set wksSource = wkbSource.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Const wsOriginalBook As String = "theFILE.xlsm"
    Const sPath As String = "C:\examplefolder\" 'this is PATH

    SourceRow = 5

''ENSURE SELECT SOURCE SHEET
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select

Do While Cells(SourceRow, "C").Value <> ""

    FileName1 = wksSource.Range("A" & SourceRow).Value
    FileName2 = wksSource.Range("L" & SourceRow).Value
    EditRow = 2
    sFile = sPath & FileName1 & "\" & FileName2 & ".xlsm"

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(sFile)

''DIM OPEN WORKBOOK
    Dim AWorkbook As Workbook
    Set AWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook

        With AWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents
            .Remove.Item ("NewJobEvent")
        End With

''CLOSE WORKBOOK W/O BEFORE SAVE
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

    Windows("theFILE.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select

SourceRow = SourceRow + 1 ' Move down 1 row for source sheet

Loop
End Sub
```

Any and all help and pointers are greatly appreciated ahead of time.

Comment: What's the specific problem though?  Also, please do us all (and you) a favor and indent your code

Comment: firstly, I'm getting a "compile error: Argument not optional" on the line, '.Remove.Item("NewJobEvent"). 

Secondly, How do I import the new Userform?

Comment: It's all here: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx

```
Sub DeleteModule()
    Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
    Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent

    Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
    Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents("Module1")
    VBProj.VBComponents.Remove VBComp
End Sub
```

`Remove` take a module reference, not a string

To import a module from a file:

```
ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Import FullPathHere
```

Comment: Note that there's a bug in the VBIDE API when importing a UserForm component, that will insert an empty line at the top of the module, so the imported code won't be 100% identical to the file on disk (shouldn't matter for OP's purposes though) - also the .frx file must be in the same path as the imported .frm.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - thanks for the clarifications/additions

Comment: @Tim Williams thanks for your advice! I now have a 'Compile Error: User-defined type not defined'.

Comment: @Kenny you need to 1) read the linked article, and 2) reference the VBE Extensibility type library.

Comment: thanks for the help the link was very informative. It seamed to work when I check 'Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3' under VBA window, tools - References